# Bypassing one of the SUMIFS criteria+criterion if the particular cell is blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

Need help:
From the table image below, the result I want in cell M5 using SUMIFS formula is that if cell K5 (validation filter) is blank or "" then the formula of **D5:D6,K5** should just bypass.

So the result in M5 should be **3** because we will bypass criterion of D5:D6 since K5 is blank.

I tried the formula:

=sumifs(E5:E6,
A5:A6,H5,
B5:B6,I5,
C5:C6,J5,
**D5:D6,K5="<>")**

with the assumption that with **="<>"** I would have been able to bypass that D5:D6 criteria.

I know that it can be easily done by removing the **D5:D6,K5="<>" part, but I need some dynamic formula so then in the future if i want to change K5 with another data validation (say: 'sublookup1') it can easily get the *new-matched-criterions-result* without changing the formula.

hope someone can help, appreciate it!

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but it sounds like you could use a helper cell that contains a reference to the cell to be used in the formula.  So initially, it would contain the value K5.  If you want to use a different cell, replace the value k5 with a reference to the new cell.  Then in your formula, replace the k5 reference with an INDIRECT function that points to the helper cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I would like to suggest the **SUMPRODUCT** function warped with **SUM**, instead of **SUMIFS**:*

[image]

- An Array Formula in Cell `K2`:

  `{=IF(ISBLANK($J2),SUM(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$3=$G$2)*($B$2:$B$3=$H$2)*($C$2:$C$3=$I$2))*($E$2:$E$3)),"")}`

**How it works:**

- `IF(ISBLANK($J2)` bypasses the **Sub-Lookup** criteria in `D2:D3`.
- *The reason I found using the SUMPRODCT is that, it stick with the criteria in `G2, H2 & I2`, if doesn't matches with their respective data then returns `0`, but SUMIFS fails to test criteria.*

*Check the Screen Shot below:*

[image]

**N.B.**

- Find the change in Cell `H2`.
- SUMPRODUCT in Cell `K2` returns `0` but still the SUMIFS get the result in Cell `K4`.
- Formula in Cell `K4` is:

  `=IF(ISBLANK(J2),SUM(SUMIFS(E2:E3,A2:A3,G2:G3,B2:B3,H2:H3,C2:C3,I2:I3),E2:E3),"")`

**Note,** with SUMPRODUCT & SUMIFS, SUM is required otherwise it returns `1` & `0`.

*You may adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: Glad to help you @freakyholic keep asking !

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested IF to solve your problem :

`=sumifs(E5:E6, A5:A6,H5, B5:B6,I5, C5:C6,J5, D5:D6,IF(K5="", "*", K5))`

This way it'll use `*` (anything) if K5 is empty, and use value in K5 otherwise.